# SQL Query to find two values attached to a single user via an ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hopefully, the title makes sense.

I've got a Postgres SQL DB. I'd like to search my data and find all users that have two Instagram handles attached to them (these IG handles will share one ID that is linked to the user).

I've got a rough idea but I've only been able to do this in Trevor.IO and I'd like to have more experience running SQL properly through something like DBeaver.

Thanks

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Show us some sample data and the expected output. Without these information it is quite hard to write a correct query.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a normalized table which applies users to instagram handles, it would be something like this:

```
SELECT
    user
FROM
    instagram_handle_table
GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```